# Can I locate my android phone?

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread

I brought a new Samsung Galaxy Y inbuilt with Android 2.3.5 some month ago and sold it recently. But after selling I noticed that in that Android I left my email ID (email ID that is used to log in to android for the first time).

I don't worry about the my email ID as I have changed its password but **Can I locate my android device with that email?** or by any other way? on any Google Maps like service?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, you would need an application like "[Where's My Droid](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.alienmanfc6.wheresmyandroid&hl=en)" installed on the device and know the phone number for the device.

If you sold the device, the new owner probably did a factory reset on the device so your information is no longer associated to the device.

In the future, before you sell your device, you should go in and do a factory reset so you are not giving the device away with any of your information.

I want to add my opinion on these apps that claim to help you find your device (including "Where's My Droid") if it is lost or stolen. They are great if you lost your phone in your house (or somewhere "safe") but if you lost it at like a bar or if someone actually stole it, chances are you will not even be able to use this software. A factory reset can be done on any device rather quickly, which would remove your "locating software" and remove any "tie" that your accounts may have to the device. Also, they require the device be ON, so if someone does steal your phone, all they have to do is turn it off, and when they have a chance, do a factory reset. My best advice I can give you is to remember that these are ~$600 devices (what you will pay off contract, or for a replacement) so treat it like it is a ~$600 device and don't leave it laying around. I am not saying that I would ever take someones phone or anything, but I could have the device factory reset by the time I got to the door to leave. It is as easy as `Menu -> Settings -> Privacy -> Factory Data Reset`.

Comment: I have changed the password of my account, what would be effect on that mobile? Would that phone still working? or the user would have prompt to enter another (his) email id?

Comment: How can he reset to factory setting? I think he need the password of my account to do a reset.

Comment: The password change you did will cause the device to no longer have access to the account. He can do a factory reset a couple ways, the easiest is in the settings menu like I mention at the end of my answer. It does not require your password or your account.

Answer (score 3):

As Ryan Conrad already pointed out, the new owner probably did a factory reset when they bought the device. However, it is indeed possible to locate it if it is still connected to the account, with an application such as Lookout's [Plan B](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.lookout.labs.planb). According to its description, it can be downloaded from the Android Market online directly to the device (if still connected to your Google account) and would upon installation send an email to your email address.

**DISCLAIMER:** I do not in any way, shape or form actually encourage you to do something like this, and though I assuming you asked this as a hypothetical question, I can't understate that this is ethically wrong to do, and possibly also illegal in some areas without the owner's consent.

Comment: the problem with any of these (wheres my droid, plan b, etc) they have to be installed on the device prior. And the email password has already been changed, which means its no longer connected to the device as the authentication token is no longer valid, even if the password is changed back, it will not automatically connect back to the account.

Comment: You are probably right in your second point, but the fact of the matter is that Plan B **does not** have to be installed prior, and, as far as I know, it is the only app of its kind that can do this.

Comment: according to [this](https://support.mylookout.com/entries/20865091-how-does-plan-b-work) you still have to install plan b, it is just doing it via the web interface. and if the account is not tied to the device any more, it wont work. plus, you need to text the word 'locate' to the number, if they change the SIM, you wont know the number.

Comment: You install the app from Android Market on a computer (no need for access to the phone), and it autoconfigures and starts itself upon installation on the device. You only need to send a text if you already have it installed (because installing it twice won't work).

Comment: right, but seeing as the device was sold to someone else, there is a new SIM in the device so being able to send the text is not really possible, unless the new number is known. Also the password has been changed for the account so it is no longer even tied to the device, and probably has been factory reset. Which would make plan B useless if you ask me, even if your phone was lost/stolen. A factory reset could be done as you are walking away with the device.

Comment: I know that Plan B is useless under those circumstances (I never said otherwise), however, the OP asked if there is any way to locate a device with the connected email, and that is what I answered.

Answer (score 0):

there is also the utrack feature by Samsung for those purposes on S G Y. but it needs to be prepared, which seems to be not the case here.